# Wp не видит язык плагин, настройка .po .mo

Tags: wordpress

```
http://bilim.astana.kz/archives/50353
```

Получается тут язык kz_KZ, kk и почему то мои файлы с аналогичными названиями и переводами календаря не используются а юзается ru_RU хотя по умолчанию engl должен был быть

Answer (score 0):

Используйте http://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/ для работы с файлами перевода, как закончите просто удалите что бы не мешал, он сам все настроит